# How to use developer console in salesforce?

Tags: apex, developer-console

I am writing apex class in developer console in salesforce but it cannot save in my salesforce account. Help me in this regard

Comment: Is there an error, if so what is it?

Comment: there is no issue in my code, no error there

Comment: But what is the developer console doing, how do you know it's not saving?

Comment: Could you please describe the process how you created and save class in developer console?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an infrequently encountered but annoying bug within the product - or at least other people are seeing the same problem: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jhavAAA

Have you tried using [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com) as an editor instead of the developer console?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend never using the online editor for your salesforce code.  You are really limiting yourself by not using a real IDE such as Eclipse or MavensMate.

Eclipse isntallation instructions: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation

I'm not as familiar with setting up MavensMate but I do know lots of people have had success with it.

That said, you definitely need more detail in your question other than saying it's not working.